# MS- Access 101 - Sum expression as part of an aggregate function

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I've just switching back to MS Access (been on Excel VBA for a year) and my SQL is a bit rusty ... I'm getting an error

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified
>   expression (Sum line below) as pat of an aggregate function

from this code:

```
SELECT 
    FYF.ACNT_CODE, 
    FYF.[Team code], 
    Sum([FYF]![Value])*(1+[IncreaseAssumptions]![Amount]) AS [Year 1 Cost] 
INTO [Year 1 costs]
FROM FYF 
INNER JOIN 
    (SunAccounts INNER JOIN IncreaseAssumptions ON SunAccounts.IncreaseType = IncreaseAssumptions.IncreaseType) 
    ON FYF.ACNT_CODE = SunAccounts.Account_Code
WHERE (((IncreaseAssumptions.YearName)="Year 1"))
GROUP BY FYF.ACNT_CODE, FYF.[Team code];
```

Where am I going wrong? The Sum part in Access is defined as an expression in the Total: line

Cheers

Comment: *in the Total: line* -- of what?

Comment: on the Access Query design page. You have rows for Field, Table, total; the non-aggregated fields are classed as Group By on the total row, but the Sum is defined as an expression (calculation)

Comment: Ah, of course. In German Access, this query designer row is *Function*, that's why I didn't recognize it.

Comment: I don't really know why Access can't do this in one query. But it should work if you save the query without GROUP BY / Sum as base query, and then create a second query, based on the first one, that does the grouping and summing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a bracketing issue - this:

```
Sum([FYF]![Value])*(1+[IncreaseAssumptions]![Amount]) AS [Year 1 Cost]
```

Should be:

```
Sum([FYF]![Value]*(1+[IncreaseAssumptions]![Amount])) AS [Year 1 Cost]
```